# Getting tokens from a string(stdin)

Tags: c, token, tokenize, strtok

I have to make my own version of bash, but i'm currently stuck on getting tokens.

Purpose of this program is that user inserts the command and the program executes it(like bash). Commands flow from stdin(when enter/return is hit, execute).

I have a problem when I want to separate a command and arguments, for example `echo lol` i want an array(pointer or something better?) that will store command `echo` and argument `lol`.

I tried it like this but I'm not sure I'm even on the right path. Any constructive suggestions?

```
char *tokens;
char *arg[10];
char command[100];
int token_counter;

while(scanf("%50[^\n]", line) != EOF){ 

    tokens = strtok(line, " ");
    command = tokens;
    token_counter = 0;
    while(tokens = strtok(NULL, " ")){
          arg[token_counter] = tokens
              token_counter++;
    }

        switch(command){

            command1 :
              //code
              break;

            command2 :
              //code
              break;

            ...

        }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to change your while to this:

while(tokens == strtok(NULL, " ")

Use equality operator, the solo ' = ' is assignment operator.

Comment: The code looks alright. @TheCrafter the assignment is fine. `while` will check the value on the LHS for null.

Comment: @user2202368 `command = tokens` doesn't work, `command` is an array. And you didn't declare `line`. The general idea is OK although you should read the whole line instead of cutting off at 50 (even if you discard the end)

Comment: @MattMcNabb How would i change it so that it would read the full line? leave the 50? how would i store the name of the command then? i can't use a pointer because when `tokens` changes `command` changes

Comment: You could read the 50 and then discard characters up to and including the next newline. Or you could dynamically allocate memory as you go. You should store these characters in an array. The `strtok` function returns pointers into the same array; if that is not suitable then you will have to take a copy of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use linked list for the parsing : for simple commands, array may be ok but if you want to do a real shell, it will be difficult.

LL parser can be interesting for you : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser